# dependsOnMethods which returns a value

Tags: java, testng

I have a trivial scenario in which a method is dependent on other
method. And the other method returns a value -
So the class looks as -

public class Temp1 {

```
    @Test
    public Integer test1() {
            Reporter.log("<b>in test1</b>");
            System.out.println("in test1");

            return null;

    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"test1"})
    public void test2() {
            Reporter.log("in test2");
            System.out.println("in test2");
    }
```

}

Now when I execute this, I encounter following exception -

```
org.testng.TestNGException:
com.core.tests.Temp1.test2() is depending on nonexistent method
com.core.tests.Temp1.test1
        at
org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.findMethodsNamed(MethodHelper.java:
143)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.topologicalSort(MethodHelper.java:
472)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.sortMethods(MethodHelper.java:
544)
        at
org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.internalCollectAndOrderMethods(MethodHelper.java:
77)
        at
org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.collectAndOrderMethods(MethodHelper.java:
49).........................
```

Though if there is no return type with method test1(), it works well.
Is there any way to get through this?

Thanks
~T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it seems not to be mentioned in the documentation, I also experienced that classes annotated with `@Test` must have a `void` return type. If you need data provided by some other method, you could try the [Data Provider mechanism](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters) of TestNG.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I also explained this on the testng-users list earlier today.

Comment: Cedric confirmed the same here - http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/035e8b0724eae23b